# neo4j CYPHER non-symmetric query response

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using neo4j cypher in order to pass some queries into my (pretty large) database of related entities.

In particular, I need to find all the nodes of type `annotation` or `physical_entity` that are connected by a single relationship to a node of type `annotation`.

My understanding is that a query for undirected connection such as below, would return in `N` all the nodes of type `annotation` and `physical_entity` that are connected to another node of type `annotation`.

```
MATCH (N)-[r]-(M)
WHERE ((N.parse_type='physical_entity' OR N.parse_type='annotation')
AND M.parse_type='annotation')
RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT(N))

> 63311
```

Whereas if I ask for `M`, it will only return only nodes of type `annotation` that are linked to other nodes of type `annotation`, which would be a subset of nodes from the previous query (ie results of the previous query minus the nodes that are `physical_entity`).

```
MATCH (N)-[r]-(M)
WHERE ((N.parse_type='physical_entity' OR N.parse_type='annotation')
AND M.parse_type='annotation')
RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT(M))

> 47355
```

However, this is not the case. There are some nodes of type `annotation` in the second query that are not in the first query:

```
MATCH (N)-[r]-(M)
WHERE ((N.parse_type='physical_entity' OR N.parse_type='annotation')
AND M.parse_type='annotation')
WITH [N, M] as tl
UNWIND tl as n
RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT(n))

> 633554
```

Why?

Comment: Your assumption for the second query isn't correct. Returning `count(DISTINCT M)` will return annotation nodes connected to EITHER a physical_entity OR annotation node. You would need to modify your WHERE clause if you wanted only annotations connected to other annotations.

Comment: Ok, got it - so the annotation nodes connected only to `physical_enitity` would not appear among `N` of the first query.

Comment: Just look at your WHERE clause. M nodes will always be annotation nodes. N nodes could be annotation nodes or physical_entity nodes. If you need tighter restrictions, then change your WHERE clause. If you have paths in your graph such that one annotation node (let's say n1) is connected to another annotation node (let's say n2), then those nodes will show up at least twice: one MATCHed path  where n1 = N and n2 = M, and another MATCHed path where n2 = N and n1 = M. That is because both paths fit the restrictions of your WHERE clause.